# Equal distributing algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, distribution, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods

I am working on developing an Event distribution application. I have an large list of events for a month. Events objects contains start and end times.

```
public class Event {
    long eventID;

    Calendar startTime;
    Calendar endTime;

    .......
}
```

I want to separate above list into N number of parts.

```
Map<Integer, List<Event>> eventLists;
```

The requirements are : 
size of the each blocks should be nearly equal and **the distribution of the each parts should distribute equally in the month**.

Is there any well known algorithm that suits to solve this problem. I would prefer, if someone could provide an accurate solution or any reference to any well known algorithm.

I'm looking for an **algorithm with statistical analysis**.

this is an simple example what I seeking for. But it should contains statistical analysis to distribute equal.

```
Calendar monthStart = EventUtil.getMonthStart();
Calendar monthEnd = EventUtil.getMonthEnd();

Calendar oneDayRange = Calendar.getInstance();
oneDayRange.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

int index = 0;

while (!monthStart.after(monthEnd)) {

    Iterator<Event> it = events.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Event e = it.next();

        if(!e.getStartTime().before(monthStart) && !e.getStartTime().after(oneDayRange)) {
            eventLists.get(index % N).add(e);
            it.remove();
            index++;
        }

    }

    monthStart.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    oneDayRange.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: What does the integer key in the map represent?

Comment: This sounds very much like you are dropping your homework here; and asking people to provide a full answer. If you want to receive helpful answers, show us what you have done so far. Otherwise, you will mostly collect downvotes.

Comment: Jägermeister I'm not dropping homework and I'm trying to get more mathematically good solution

Answer (score 1):

If the event duration has to be taken into account, the problem described is a generalization of the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is `NP`-hard, but admits a [polynomial time approximation scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme). If the event durations are not important and a round-robin assignment to the `N` slots can be done in linear time.